# Timeout Exception for process that creating word file

Tags: java, documents4j

I created a word file using documents4j library.

Sometimes it works, but another times it doesn't work and go through timeout excepction.

Here are output error:

```
ERROR c.d.c.msoffice.MicrosoftWordBridge - Thread responsible for running script timed out: C:\****\****\****\word_start287628854.vbs

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for Process[pid=15988, exitValue="not exited"] to finish, timeout: 5000 milliseconds, executed command [cmd, /S, /C, "C:\****\****\****\word_start287628854.vbs""] in directory C:\****\****\Desktop, output was 0 bytes:

at org.zeroturnaround.exec.ProcessExecutor.newTimeoutException(ProcessExecutor.java:1079) ~[zt-exec-1.8.jar:na]
    at org.zeroturnaround.exec.ProcessExecutor.waitFor(ProcessExecutor.java:1042) ~[zt-exec-1.8.jar:na]
    at org.zeroturnaround.exec.ProcessExecutor.execute(ProcessExecutor.java:860) ~[zt-exec-1.8.jar:na]
    at com.documents4j.conversion.AbstractExternalConverter.runNoArgumentScript(AbstractExternalConverter.java:72) ~[documents4j-util-transformer-process-1.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.documents4j.conversion.msoffice.AbstractMicrosoftOfficeBridge.runNoArgumentScript(AbstractMicrosoftOfficeBridge.java:51) ~[documents4j-transformer-msoffice-base-1.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.documents4j.conversion.msoffice.AbstractMicrosoftOfficeBridge.tryStart(AbstractMicrosoftOfficeBridge.java:34) ~[documents4j-transformer-msoffice-base-1.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.documents4j.conversion.msoffice.MicrosoftWordBridge.startUp(MicrosoftWordBridge.java:44) ~[documents4j-transformer-msoffice-word-1.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.documents4j.conversion.msoffice.MicrosoftWordBridge.<init>(MicrosoftWordBridge.java:39) ~[documents4j-transformer-msoffice-word-1.0.3.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at com.documents4j.conversion.ExternalConverterDiscovery.make(ExternalConverterDiscovery.java:30) ~[documents4j-transformer-1.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.documents4j.conversion.ExternalConverterDiscovery.makeAll(ExternalConverterDiscovery.java:42) ~[documents4j-transformer-1.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.documents4j.conversion.ExternalConverterDiscovery.loadConfiguration(ExternalConverterDiscovery.java:85) ~[documents4j-transformer-1.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.documents4j.conversion.DefaultConversionManager.<init>(DefaultConversionManager.java:22) ~[documents4j-transformer-1.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter.makeConversionManager(LocalConverter.java:79) ~[documents4j-local-1.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter.<init>(LocalConverter.java:51) ~[documents4j-local-1.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter$Builder.build(LocalConverter.java:186) ~[documents4j-local-1.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.processmining.framework.util.ui.scalableview.interaction.ExportInteractionPanel.export(ExportInteractionPanel.java:408) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.processmining.framework.util.ui.scalableview.interaction.ExportInteractionPanel$1.run(ExportInteractionPanel.java:78) ~[bin/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to close the word document before running the app.

Try to kill the runnig proccess, from CMD in Windoes OS you can run the command:

```
taskkill /F /PID your_pid_number
```

For example you can see the the app waiting for proccess **15988** to finish
`java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for Process[pid=15988, exitValue="not exited"] to finish...`

Therefore you can run the command:

```
taskkill /F /PID 15988
```

and then running your app

Comment: It is a new execution, it tries to create another word file independent from those create in a previous execution.

Comment: @jumpy If you close the previews word document, you still get this exception?

Comment: It is closed. Now it works, but if I re-run the app multiple times closing the previous excecution it is probably that one of these execution go through TimeoutException.

Comment: When you get this exception, kill the proccess that couse this, like I wrote in my answer

Comment: I tried with the right PID. Its output is "process not found"

Comment: From the error it looks like the app waits for some proccess to finish, when you get this error kill the proccess and re-run the app

Comment: How can I avoid these on-the-fly without entering on prompt?

Comment: @jumpy It's hard to tell without seeing your code (post it on separate post). but one option is to catch the exeption and to kill the proccess from the code instead of doing it manually